# AlarmManager will not fire with custom Calendar object

Tags: java, android

I am trying to set an alarm using custom times, and nothing I am doing is working. The only way my AlarmManager will fire is if I use `Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis().`

To get my times, I retrieved them from a SQLite database. I double checked and none of the values are null.

```
    for (QueuePostFb q : queueFb)
    { 
        String day = q.getDay(); 
        String month = q.getMonth(); 
        String year = q.getYear(); 
        String hour = q.getHour(); 
        String minute = q.getMinute(); 
        String amPm = q.getAmPm(); 
        String message = q.getMessage(); 
        String token = q.getTokens(); 
        String photoUri = q.getAttachmentUris(); 

        int m = Integer.parseInt(month); 
        int d = Integer.parseInt(day); 
        int y = Integer.parseInt(year); 
        int mi = Integer.parseInt(minute);
        int h = Integer.parseInt(hour); 

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        if (amPm.equals("AM")){ 
            c.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
        }
        else if (amPm.equals("PM")){
            c.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);             
        }

        AlarmManager fAm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE); 

        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, d);
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, y);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mi);
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, m);
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR, h);

        Intent fService = new Intent(this, QueuedService.class); 

        fService.putExtra("fb_token", token);
        fService.putExtra("fb_photo_uri", photoUri); 
        fService.putExtra("fb_message", message); 
        fService.putExtra("type", "Facebook");

        PendingIntent fPi = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, fService, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // Will work if Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTimeInMillis()
        fAm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), fPi);
    }
```

Comment: After calling setter methods on Calendar object print the date like System.out.println(c.getTime()); and ensure that correct date and time what you expecting is printing.